# Can I have more than one custom Authorize attribute on a controller method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I created a new Authorize attribute like this:

```
public class ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string claimType;
    private int[] claimAllowedValues;

    public ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute(string type, int[] allowedValues)
    {
        this.claimType = type;
        this.claimAllowedValues = allowedValues;
    }

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {

        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity;
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        if (!(httpContext.User.Identity is ClaimsIdentity))
        {
            return false;
        }

        claimsIdentity = httpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        var identityClaimValue = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(claimType).Value;

        if (identityClaimValue != null && 
            claimAllowedValues.Any(n => (n == Int32.Parse(identityClaimValue))))
        {
            return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

It is used here:

```
[ClaimsAuthorize("Role", new[] { 1, 2, 3 })]
```

I would like to create another authorize attribute.

Is it possible to create another and then have two of them decorate a method like this:

```
 [ClaimsAuthorize("Role", new[] { 1, 2, 3 })]
 [OtherAuthorize("abc", 1)]
 [RoutePrefix("api/Question")]
 public class QuestionController : BaseController
```

Comment: Are you expecting it to And or Or. Do you require both or one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that will make sense, you can achieve the same thing by adding more properties like type of authorization for example to your custom authorize attribute and set these properties when you decorate your class depending of the required scenario.